Is there a need to disable CDP domains before disconnecting?
If I connect to a chromium browser using playwright over the CDP, and then I enable some domains like Fetch.enable, do I need to make sure to call Fetch.disable before closing the created CDP session, or is it fine to leave it, and will playwright disable it when I call cdp.detach()?
const cdp = await page.context().newCDPSession(page)
await cdp.send("Fetch.enable": {
  patterns: [
    urlPattern: "*", resourceType: "Document", requestStage: "Request" },
]})
cdp.detach()

More generally, do I need to disable domains at all if I'm using the CDP, say even directly outside of using Playwright?
